# Understanding non lexical lifetimes when calling functions that return reference

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, ownership, borrowing

The following function works fine with regards to NLL

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = 1i32;
    let mut y = &mut x;

    let z = &mut y; 

    *y = 12;
}
```

However if I replace the  statement `let z = &mut y` with a function call (that basically does the same thing), the borrow checker complains.

```
fn test<'a>(x:&'a mut &'a mut i32) -> &'a mut i32 {
    &mut **x
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = 1i32;
    let mut y = &mut x;

    let z = test(&mut y);

    *y = 12;
}
```

gives the following error:

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `*y` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:11:5
   |
9  |     let z = test(&mut y);
   |                  ------ borrow of `*y` occurs here
10 |     
11 |     *y = 12;
   |     ^^^^^^^
   |     |
   |     assignment to borrowed `*y` occurs here
   |     borrow later used here
```

The reference returned by the function `test()` is not used anymore, so shouldn't it be considered 'dead'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's give some names to the lifetimes in your program. (This won't compile, but is for demonstrative purposes.)

In your first example, we have get two lifetimes, `'1` and `'2`. The lifetime `'2` only lasts for a single line, so `y` can be used later on:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut x = 1i32;      //
    let mut y = &'1 mut x; //        ^
                           //        |
    let z = &'2 mut y;     //  |'2   |'1
                           //        |
    *y = 12;               //        v
}
```

In the second example, because  `test` requires `&'a mut &'a mut i32` where `'a` represent identical lifetimes, the outer reference must live as long as the inner reference. This is why we get an error:

```rust
fn test<'a>(x:&'a mut &'a mut i32) -> &'a mut i32 {
    &mut **x
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = 1i32;        //
    let mut y = &'1 mut x;   //        ^
                             //        |
    let z = test(&'2 mut y); //  |'2   |'1
                             //  |     |
    *y = 12;                 //  v     v
}
```

If we give `test` two distinct lifetimes, however, the code will now compile fine because we are back in the same situation as in the first example:

```rust
fn test<'a, 'b>(x:&'a mut &'b mut i32) -> &'a mut i32 {
    &mut **x
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = 1i32;        //
    let mut y = &'1 mut x;   //        ^
                             //        |
    let z = test(&'2 mut y); //  |'2   |'1
                             //        |
    *y = 12;                 //        v
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I completely overlooked the power of a function here. It can "forcefully drag" the lifetimes further, when it has a returning reference :)